# Visual Basic 6.0 to aspx Migration Printer

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, vb6

Im transferring vb6 application functions to web application aspx but the problem is vb6 has a ini file in client machine it has clients receipt printer name when it prints it will automatically take the receipt printer name from that ini file and print..

can this apply in c# website?
can we create a notepad file or ini file and take the printer and print the reciept?

Comment: Without a local installed browser plugin (activex, or a Browser Helper Object) you have no way to get to any resource on a client box. You'll have to create something like a userprofile in your webapp where the user can configure that kind of info. That info is stored server side.

Comment: you mean every browser has to install  plugin?and whats the purpose of saving it in server side?is there is anyother method?

Comment: The usual trick involves relaxed security settings to permit use of an embedded Java applet, ActiveX library, or blob of .Net exposed/wrapped/GACced as an ActiveX library.  I can't say a BHO can't do this, but it isn't the first option that comes to mind. All bets are off for non-IE browsers.  Remember "web application" is a contradiction in terms, meant as a desperation hack for public-facing interactions and not viable for real applications.  Web browsers have to be secured and are hazardous enough as they are.